# How to get user information on a Mac?

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, domain, users

How would I get user information from a Mac such as user domain, etc. through a Terminal command?

I've tried dscl as well as dscacheutil, but they don't really have what I'm looking for. I was wondering if there any other options out there for retrieving user information. If not, I'll make do with these two commands.

Comment: When you say "domain", what exactly are you referring to? An Active directory domain? LDAP? How is the system configured to be on the domain?

Comment: An active directory domain.

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished by using `ls -l /Users/`

and will be returned something similar to:

> drwxrwxrwt   5 root                   wheel  170 Feb  1  2012 Shared
>
> drwxr-xr-x+ 12 DOMAIN\finalcuteditor  staff  408 Sep  7  2011
>   finalcuteditor
>
> drwxr-xr-x+ 19 local-admin            staff  646 Sep 18 20:50
>   local-admin

...where DOMAIN\user will give you the information you are looking for.

Also, you may find value in this command: `dscl . readall /users` or for less verbose information you may find what you need using `dscl . readall /users | grep username`

...`dscl` tip taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308064/805031

Comment: That will provide you with the Domain, as you asked. It seems you are looking for other information as well. If so, let me know and I will post back. I am currently investigating this as well, why I found your post, and have a post here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83943/command-line-query-account-type-local-network-managed-mobile